# Blazor: Incrementing an existing @foreach from a list

Tags: c#, foreach, blazor, increment

I have a MySQL database from which I am creating a list and then using a @foreach to display in a table.  I currently have a "0" as a placeholder in my table, but I need the first one to be 1, then 2, etc.  I don't want to use the existing key because I filter the list (selectedUser) & want the list to always show the number of entries, not how to reference it in the database.

```
@foreach (var u in Users.Where(d => d.User == selectedUser))
{
    <tr>
        <td title="">0</td>
        <td>@u.User</td>
        <td>@u.UserLevel</td>
        <td>(you get the idea)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Pertinent part of my @code block:

```
List<DBTestModel> Users;    

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        string sql = "select * from MyTable";
        Users = await _data.LoadData<DBTestModel, dynamic>(sql, new { }, _config.GetConnectionString("default"));
    }
```

I'm still pretty new to this (and this is my first foray into development beyond very simple UI), so please forgive a question that does get asked a fair bit; I did a lot of Googling & found many answers, but I couldn't apply any directly to this situation (I think because people just included the part of theirs that was broken & I needed to see the whole of it to understand it).  I believe the pieces I need are:

```
var i = 0;
```

and

```
i++;
```

but I'm just not seeming to get them in the right place.

Comment: Define your variable before the for-each loop. Then you can increase the counter within the for-each loop and use it as a value to display in the table cell.

Comment: What is the type of `Users`? `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: Note: use variable for Users.Where(d => d.User == selectedUser), its too slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
@{ var x = 1; }
@foreach (var u in Users.Where(d => d.User == selectedUser))
    {
        <tr>
            <td title="">@x</td>
            <td>@u.User</td>
            <td>@u.UserLevel</td>
            <td>(you get the idea)</td>
        </tr>
    x++;
    }
```

### Ammendment

My actual test code looked like this:

```
@page "/Test"

@{ var x = 1;}
@foreach (var c in Cities)
{
    <div> @x - @c</div>
    x++;
}

@code {
    private List<string> Cities => new List<string>() { "Adijan", "Lagos", "Tripoli" };
}
```

Which gives you:
[image]

I just transposed the question code in.

Comment: This got me there & was ultimately what I was trying to do; was there perhaps a typo, though?  It didn't work as you entered it, but when I updated it to be this it worked:
@{ var x = 1; The_foreach_statement } (moving the first "}" to the end - I can't enter it in a readable way here).

Comment: Probably (didn't actually run the code I wrote and said something like!!), as long as you fixed it.

Comment: Nope, that wasn't the problem, I guarantee you.  If it were, then the compiler would reject the use of the variable `x` in the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Users` is an `IEnumerable<T>`, how about creating an extension method to expose an index for each item in the enumerable?

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{    
    public static IEnumerable<(int Index, T Item)> WithIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        }

        return source.Select((item, index) => (index, item));
    }
}
```

You would then be able to do:

```
@foreach (var result in Users.Where(d => d.User == selectedUser).WithIndex())
{
    <tr>
        <td title="">@result.Index</td>
        <td>@result.Item.User</td>
        <td>@result.Item.UserLevel</td>
    </tr>
}
```

[Blazor REPL](https://blazorrepl.com/repl/wPkebDPq16XaUXWK52)

Answer (score 0):

The below worked - big thank you to all that responded!

```
{ var i = 1; 
    @foreach (var u in Users.Where(d => d.User == selectedUser))
    {
        <tr>
            <td title="">@i</td>
            <td>@u.User</td>
            <td>@u.UserLevel</td>
            <td>(you get the idea)</td>
        </tr>
        i++
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you literally just copied Shaun Curtis' idea, I'd recommend marking it as the answer.

Comment: I tried at the time, but got a message about having to wait two days - thanks for the reminder, I just did :-)